# cant open one tk window per thread , tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I want to write a program which every time accept a message pop-up a window at the corner of the desktop.

I use the web server to accept message.

And my Tk code is like this:

```
import threading
from Tkinter import *
import time

def alert():
  alert = Tk()
  alert.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", alert.quit)
  alert.mainloop()

def run():
  th = threading.Thread(target=alert)
  th.start()

if __name__ == 'main':
  run()
  time.sleep(5)

  run()
  time.sleep(5)

  run()
```

When I ran this, only one window pop-up. It seems that the program hang-up when the second thread went 'alert = Tk()', I'm not sure.

The third thread never ran.

If I didn't close the window before the second thread started, the window would be out of response.

I want to know what's wrong with my code and how tkinter works.

Thanks

Comment: why are you using threads? You can open hundreds or thousands of windows in a single thread.

Comment: @BryanOakley mainloop() hang up

Comment: You need to run your web server in a thread, and keep tkinter in the main thread.  Your other code can put a message on a queue, and your main thread can poll the queue and display the messages. tkinter isn't designed to run in more than one thread.

Comment: @BryanOakley mainloop() hang up the thread of the RequestHandler, and the request never response. I'm not familiar with tk, I just thought about using threading.

Comment: @BryanOakley ok, I will try this. But why tkinter must run in main thread. It seems really different from java.

Comment: Why must tkinter run in the main thread? It can probably run in any thread, but you should only ever have exactly one instance of `Tk` running during the life of your program. The reason is that each instance of `Tk` gets a fresh copy of a Tcl interpreter, and these interpreters can't be shared across python threads.